# How to create Diagrams using Wolfram / Mathematica?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization, labeling, charts

How can one use Wolfram to make diagrams like

> [image]

with the arrows labeled as well (to label "mediating factors" between the causal elements)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
vertices = {"rush hour", "bad weather", "accident", "traffic jam", "sirens"};

edges = DirectedEdge @@@ {"rush hour" -> "traffic jam", "bad weather" -> "accident", 
      "accident" -> "traffic jam", "bad weather" -> "traffic jam", 
      "accident" -> "sirens"};

edgelabels = RandomWord["Noun", Length @ edges];

Graph[edges, 
 PlotTheme -> "IndexLabeled", 
 VertexSize -> Large, 
 EdgeLabels -> Thread[edges -> edgelabels]]
```

[image]

Use additional options to embellish the picture:

```
elabeling = AssociationThread[edges, edgelabels];

eSF = {Arrowheads[{{.04, .75}, 
    {.05, .45, Graphics @ Text[Framed[Style[elabeling @ #2, 14],
      FrameStyle -> None,  Background -> White]]}}], 
    Last @ GraphElementData["Arrow"][##]} &;

coords = Drop[Join @@ Array[{ #2, (3 - #)}&, {2, 3}], {4}]

Graph[vertices, edges, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 14, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 GraphStyle -> "IndexLabeled", 
 VertexSize -> .4, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF, 
 VertexCoordinates -> coords]
```

[image]

We can also construct the graphics primitives from scratch:

```
radius = Offset @  Max[(1.2/2) 
    Rasterize[Style[#, 14, "Graphics"], "RasterSize"][[1]] & /@ vertices];

Graphics[{{Arrowheads[{{.02, .75}, {.05, .45, 
        Graphics @Text[Framed[Style[elabeling @ #, 14], FrameStyle -> None, 
           Background -> White], {0, 0}, {0, .25}]}}], 
     Arrow[List @@ # /. Thread[vertices -> coords]]} & /@ edges, 
  FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Gray], Disk[#, radius] & /@ coords, 
  MapThread[Text, {Style[#, 16] & /@ vertices, coords}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 800, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.2]]
```

[image]

**Update:** From comments: *"Ideally a user just supplies a list of relationships (with possible labels)..."*

```
elist = {{"rush hour" -> "traffic jam",  "empty"}, 
 {"bad weather" -> "accident", "canyon"}, 
 {"accident" -> "traffic jam", "sweatshirt"}, 
 {"bad weather" -> "traffic jam", "pump"}, 
 {"accident" -> "sirens", "nominative"}};
```

You can use `` GraphComputation`LayeredGraphPlotLegacy `` or `` GraphComputation`GraphPlotLegacy `` (if you have access to versions before v12 you can use `LayeredGraphPlot` and `GraphPlot`, respectively):

```
GraphComputation`LayeredGraphPlotLegacy[elist,  
 DirectedEdges -> True, EdgeLabeling -> True, VertexLabeling -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 500, BaseStyle -> 15, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

```
GraphComputation`GraphPlotLegacy[elist,  
 DirectedEdges -> True, EdgeLabeling -> True, VertexLabeling -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 500, BaseStyle -> 15, PlotStyle -> Black,
 Method -> "LayeredDigraphDrawing"]
```

> same picture

To render vertices as disks add the option

```
VertexRenderingFunction -> ({White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#, .3], Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)
```

to get

[image]

Comment: kglr: Can you explain more the syntax behind `eSF` with `ArrowHeads`?

Comment: I'm trying to make this generalizable to arbitrary vertices/edges (including undirected edges). Ideally a user just supplies a list of relationships (with possible labels) into a function and everything is automatically drawn. I've removed the `coords` field since that lets Wolfram draw the layout.

Comment: @George, thank you for the accept. The function `eSF` takes the built-in edge shape function `GraphElementData["Arrow"]` and injects the edge label into the `Arrowheads` directive so that  the label has the same orientation as the arrow. See  [Arrowheads >> Scope >> Custom Arrowheads](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Arrowheads.html) for more examples of how custom arrowheads work. I use `coords` to match the picture. In general, it is more convenient to use the built-in vertex layouts.

Comment: kglr: I love how the `eSF` creates space in the edges so that the text is always legible (i.e., the edge and the edge label never overlap). The problem with the `eSF` is that sometimes labels can be upside down if the nodes are configured in the right way. Is there a way to adjust the `eSF` so that the labels are always rightside up (like the first graph in your answer), but the spacing in between the edges and the text is preserved so that the labels are always legible?

Comment: @George, The  graphics glyphs in custom arrowheads have the same orientation as the arrow by default. We should be able to control the orientation of the text using the fourth argument of `Text` (`Text[expr, coords, offset, dir] `) in custom arrowheads.

Answer (score 18):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
r = 1; (*radius of each disk*)

(*center of each disk. Numbers left to right, top to bottom*)
c1 = {0, 0}; c2 = {r + 2, 0}; c3 = {r + 5, 0}; c4 = {r + 2, -(r + 2)}; 
c5 = {r + 5, -(r + 2)};

makeDisk[r_, c_] := {EdgeForm[Black],LightYellow, Disk[c, r]}(*change as needed*)

makeArrow[from_, to_, dir_] := Module[{z = Cos[Pi/4]},
   Which[
    dir == "right", 
    Arrow[{{from[[1]] + r, from[[2]]}, {to[[1]] - r, to[[2]]}}],

    dir == "down", 
    Arrow[{{from[[1]], from[[2]] - r}, {to[[1]], to[[2]] + r}}],

    dir == "right-down", 
    Arrow[{{from[[1]] + z, from[[2]] - z}, {to[[1]] - z, to[[2]] + z}}],

    dir == "left-down", 
    Arrow[{{from[[1]] - z, from[[2]] - z}, {to[[1]] + z, to[[2]] + z}}]

    ]
   ];
putLabel[txt_, at_] := Style[Text[txt, at], Bold, 12]
Graphics[{
  makeDisk[1, c1],
  makeDisk[1, c2],
  makeDisk[1, c3],
  makeDisk[1, c4],
  makeDisk[1, c5],
  makeArrow[c2, c3, "right"],
  makeArrow[c2, c4, "down"],
  makeArrow[c3, c5, "down"],
  makeArrow[c1, c4, "right-down"],
  makeArrow[c3, c4, "left-down"],
  putLabel["rush hour", c1],
  putLabel["bad weather", c2],
  putLabel["accident", c3],
  putLabel["traffic jam", c4],
  putLabel["siren", c5]
  }, Axes -> False]
```